# Moving a columns in all tables in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to move the columns "pass/fail" to the end of each table in my workbook, but I'm getting an error message:

> You can't rearrange cells within a table this way, because it might
> affect other table cells in an unexpected way.

If I debug it vba highlights this part:

```
Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
```

The macro:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim Sht     As Worksheet
Dim Tbl     As ListObject

For Each sht In Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> "Original" Then
        Set Tbl = sht.ListObjects(1)
        
        With Tbl
        .ListColumns("Pass/fail").Range.Cut
        Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
        End With
        
        
        With Tbl.Sort.SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add Key:=Tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(9), _
                     SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                     Order:=xlDescending, _
                     DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        With Tbl.Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With


End If
Next sht
End Sub
```

How can I move the columns without the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with that line is that it refers to your active sheet and not to `sht`. Change it with:

```
sht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
```

and it should be fine.

Even better:

```
Tbl.Range(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Insert shift:=xlToRight
```

This way you won't have to bother changing the code if the table is moved from range A1. Note that it doesn't cut-paste the whole column, just column within the table.

Answer (score -1):

You refer to the last column of the sheet! The column right to this cell or column does not exist!

```
?Range("A1").End(xlToRight).address
$XFD$1

?Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Address
=> Error Message Application-defined or object-defined error
```

[image]